# Leaflet.timeline geojson parsing error

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Trying to implement [Leaflet.timeline](https://github.com/skeate/Leaflet.timeline) and running into a problem with either the structure of the GeoJSON or something else.

To simplify debugging I've added the geojson as a var (in reality it's dynamically created by Rails). Here's the beginning:

```
 var data = [{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"start":"1903","end":"1908","name":"part of S. Toluca St. (26). and second block south gone","title":"Was Brook before 1903 and now is part of S. Toluca St. (26). and second block south gone 1908.","link=":91},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-118.25862396508458,34.06087254304104],[-118.25933206826451,34.05994816216629]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"start":"1903","end":"1928","name":"part of E. 40th Place","title":"Was 37th St before 1903 and now is part of E. 40th Place 1928.","link=":650},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-118.25712423772116,34.01007010760971],[-118.25649456380442,34.01016443793837],[-118.25584971702219,34.01016443793837],[-118.25427932544667,34.0102021700405],[-118.25213995141625,34.010227324765935]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"start":"1903","end":"1908","name":"part of E. 9th Place (21).","title":"Was 10th St.  before 1903 and now is part of E. 9th Place (21). 1908.","link=":3},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-118.24982816353442,34.035546195508864],[-118.25104052200915,34.03663976724366]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"start":"1921","end":"","name":"Miramar St. One block abandoned","title":"Was 3rd St before 1921 and now is Miramar St. One block abandoned .","link=":645},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-118.26117539280003,34.05901974362122],[-118.2593849946753,34.05823410691563],[-118.25815599257271,34.05768101430694],[-118.25759459655055,34.05717191451128],[-118.25663111959356,34.05654339202722]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"start":"1928","end":"1930","name":"Commonwealth Pl and a portion abandoned","title":"Was Auto Pl before 1928 and now is Commonwealth Pl and a portion abandoned 1930.","link=":50},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-118.28558737412096,34.07543021182353],...
```

I get to here in the Leaflet.timeline:

```
_process(data) {
  data.features.forEach((feature) => {
```

Looking at `data`:

[image: data screen shot]

In other words, it seems to be intact and understood. If run from here it fails with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`, so reload again and stop; and in the console `data[0].features`

[image: result of data{0}.features]

and lastly `data[0].features.forEach(feature)` in the console:

[image: result of data[0].features.forEach(feature)]

What am I doing wrong or what else should I check? The geojson works with `var segmentLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('overview_data.geojson').addTo(laMap);` but I would like to add a time slider.

Not direct answer, but I solved my bigger problem of reading a GeoJSON. As I said in [Reading a GeoJSON file into Rails/Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354442/reading-a-geojson-file-into-rails-leaflet), I read the GeoJSON in with

```
$.getJSON("overview/overview_data.json", function (data) {
   <all the stuff I needed to to>
} )
```

Although it looks the same I must have restructured the GeoJSON a bit, because the problem mentioned here is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you should not have wrapped your Feature Collection in an array.

While it is true that Leaflet's [`L.geoJSON`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson) factory also accepts arrays of GeoJSON objects, it does not seem to be the case of Leaflet.timeline plugin: it tries reading directly `data.features`, as if `data` was a single Feature Collection, whereas you pass in `data` as an array of Feature Collection(s).

In your debug you even explicitly look into an item of this array: `data[0].features`

Lastly, if you write `forEach(feature)`, the JS engine expects `feature` to be a function (the callback to `forEach`), not a function parameter as it would have been if you wrote for example `forEach(feature => {console.log(feature);}`

Therefore you could very simply refactor a little bit your Rails backend to send a single Feature Collection object, not wrapped in an array.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. But the examples use more that single features, but they are both jsonp, one is a feed from https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojsonp and starts out:

Comment: You sound to mix up [Feature Collection](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.3) and [Feature](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.2). The end point you mention returns a JSONP with a _single_ **Feature Collection**, which may contain _plenty_ **Features**.

Comment: But in looking more carefully the examples do some preprocessing. I've have to look into a bit more. It's complicated by the fact that the repository doesn't match the posted examples and put the script together from pieces. Thanks for commenting. I'll look at both comments. I would have missed the distinction you have in the last comment.

Comment: I think my data is similar to the examples. But I'll look more and it probably won't be until tomorrow. @ghybs Thank you